# refactoring dot jsp dot html and other non dot java files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

Refactoring for Java ee web apps for example renaming a page name , is not done well by most ides like e.g netbeans , where I observe that the renaming (refactoring) (in this example) does not reflect the change of that name in other parts of the applicaion . eg. in froms and other pages that have links to the renamed page.

(this is contrary to normal .java files.) Is my observation correct? and what is the solution if so?  Thats my usuall practice for .java files. but thats not the case with .jsp or html or other files , even I rename  (refactor) a .java file. its not reflected in .jsp . html files. I have alot of files pointing to that renamed file... then what

well how to properly reafactor in the first place. do tell me

**Global search and replace is the last thing I and most devs want to do**

Comment: You are right; global search and replace is dangerous and we should avoid it. There is nothing wrong with a Global search alone though. Search for what you expect to replace, manually verify results, refine search if there are false positives, and repeat. Once you have gotten a good enough search, you can then do the replace with confidence. After all, when you do a "Refactor -> Rename" in an IDE, it is actually just doing a smart global search and replace under the hood.

Comment: yes. but for large projects and many files... its hell of a job to check every occurrence manully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IDE doesn't support it you're limited to normal file-based search-and-replace.

(IntelliJ, for example, finds non-code usages of strings in HTML, XML, etc. files.)

Comment: Search and replace is very sensative as it may corrupt things. and I primarily need it for netbeans.

Comment: @Masood I wouldn't suggest an automatic, global S&R, although a reasonable regex-based S&R, and limited file extensions, I'd be surprised if you'd have many false positives.

Comment: its quite sensative for S & R.  isnt there an alternative? things can go wrong easily

Comment: @Masked Use a better IDE? I don't see how a regex S&R with verification is going to cause you that many problems, though.

Comment: what IDE(s) do you recomend with such native refactoring

Comment: +1 for mentioning [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is a superior IDE in that it handles renaming accross all project files. Even if it isn't sure if it *should* do a rename (found usage in comment or whatever), it will prompt you with a "uncertain" list which you get to manually verify before proceeding. I have used IDEA since version 7 and I can't remember ever needing to second guess its refactoring tools.

Comment: hmm.. so its confirmed that there is no option else than search and Replace (else than in IDEA)? if so. iam accepting the answer with a thanks.